# How to find two strings that are close to each other

Tags: string, algorithm, closest-points

I have n strings and I want to find the closest pair.

> What's the fastest practical algorithm to find this pair?

Comment: So your dataset is 100k strings and you will have new queries arrive, or will you use as ONE query a string from the dataset?

Comment: @gsamaras For a given input of 100k strings, I want just one answer which is a pair that is closer to each other than all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper "[The Closest Pair Problem under the Hamming Metric](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-02882-3_21)", Min, Kao, Zhu seems to be what you are looking for, and it applies to finding a single closest pair.

For your case, where n<sup>0.294</sup> < D < n, where D is the dimensionality of your data (1000) and n the size of your dataset, the algorithm will run in O(n<sup>1.843</sup> D<sup>0.533</sup>).

Comment: Looking at the abstract it seems the complexity they give for a practical algorithm is O(n^2 D/log^2 D).  The other algorithm looks completely impractical to me.

Comment: Isn't the O(n^1.843  D^0.533) complexity algorithm one of the completely impractical ones from that paper?